# CDecl cleanup code in explicitly linked DLL

Tags: c++, c, dll, calling-convention, cdecl

I have a function in an unmanaged Win32 DLL that takes a variable number of arguments and therefore needs to be `__cdecl` rather than `__stdcall` or any other calling convention.  At the moment I'm linking explicitly to the DLL (which is to say, I'm using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` rather than linking to the DLL's `.lib` file).

I can call the function just fine, but since it's `cdecl` I need to add the following inline assembly instruction after each call:

```
retVal = addVecs(v1, v2, v3, v4);
__asm add esp, 64 ;Sizeof VECTOR struct is 16 bytes
printf("The sum of all these vectors is:\n\tMagnitude: %f\n\tDirection (radians): %f\n\n", retVal.mag, retVal.dir);
```

If I do not include the inline assembly then the program crashes after the call to addVecs.

Is there any way I can write either the EXE or the DLL such that the inline assembly instruction is not needed? For example, `printf` is also a `__cdecl` function yet I do not need to write inline assembly to ensure the stack is cleaned up after every call I make to it.

Comment: When you store the function pointer after calling `GetProcAddress`, do you store it in a pointer that includes `__cdecl`?

Comment: Isn't __cdecl usually the default calling convention in Win32? (At least for code compiled with MSVC, and even though the Win32 API itself doesn't use it)

Comment: @immibis You can specify the default calling convention as a compiler option.  It's not something you should rely on.  Especially when loading DLLs, you should always be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the calling convention of `addVecs` is correct.  It pays to be explicit about this, and not rely on your compiler's defaults.

```
typedef VECTOR (__cdecl *addVecs_ptr)( VECTOR, VECTOR, VECTOR, VECTOR );

static addVecs_ptr addVecs = NULL;
```

If you've used a typedef like this, it makes the cast easy later on when you're loading the address:

```
addVecs = (addVecs_ptr) GetProcAddress( hSomeDllHandle, "addVecs" );
```

Comment: Helps a lot! I've gotten used to typing in the standard CALLBACK* macro when using GetProcAddress that I forgot that that's a #define for __stdcall